# how to delete index with deleteRequest API in elasticsearch(6.4.3)

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'd like to delete index in elasticsearch 6.4.3 by using DeleteRequest API

But elastic.co guide 3 arguments(index,document,id)
(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.4/java-rest-high-document-delete.html)

I want use 2 arguments for deleting index (index,document)

So, Anybody help me about this?

```
DeleteRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest(index);
DeleteResponse response = mClient.delete(deleteRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation
>   Failed: 1: type is missing;2: id is missing;  at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.ValidateActions.addValidationError(ValidateActions.java:26)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.action.delete.DeleteRequest.validate(DeleteRequest.java:87)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1248)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.delete(RestHighLevelClient.java:681)
>     at
>   com.sds.imp.gm.comm.es.RestHighLevelClientAPI.deleteIndex(RestHighLevelClientAPI.java:52)
>     at
>   com.sds.imp.gm.comm.es.RestHighLevelClientAPI.main(RestHighLevelClientAPI.java:220)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete an index in Elastic Search, you need to use the Delete Index API
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.4/java-rest-high-delete-index.html

This is the basic example, using the synchronous execution:

```
DeleteIndexRequest request = new DeleteIndexRequest(*IndexName*);
DeleteIndexResponse deleteIndexResponse = client.indices().delete(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

The API you are using is meant to delete documents, that is why it requires 3 arguments: the name of the index, the type, and the id of the document you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
DeleteRequest request = new DeleteRequest(
    "index",   
    "doc",     
    "id");
DeleteResponse deleteResponse = client.delete(request,RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        return deleteResponse.getResult().name();
```

where "index" is the index name and id is the document id.

As per https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.4/java-rest-high-document-delete.html documentation, you need to pass 3 arguments. 2 argument should be "doc".

Comment: I found solution like this

Comment: // DeleteIndexRequest
  DeleteIndexRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteIndexRequest(index);
  // Execute delete
  DeleteIndexResponse response = mClient.indices().delete(deleteRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
  
  return response.isAcknowledged();

Comment: as per Elasticsearch client version 6.4.3 you need to pass 3 arguments. That's why you are getting the above exception. Not sure what are you trying to achieve.